# delphi строку кода переписать на php

Tags: php, delphi

delphi строку кода переписать на php

```
 var
   i : integer;
   b,Output:byte;
   k:integer;
begin
  b:=100;
  k:=11234;

Output := b XOR ( k shr  (k mod 3) );
showmessage(Output.ToString);
```

Comment: А какие вам слова неясны?

Answer (score 1):

```
b XOR ( k shr  (k mod 3) )
```

в порядке раскрытия скобок

1. остаток от деления `k mod 3` => `$k % 3`
2. битовый сдвиг вправо `k shr X` => `$k >> X`
3. исключающее Или `b xor Y` => `$b xor Y`

с данными значениями это означает следующее:

```
1.   11234 % 3 = 2
2.   11234 >> 2 
     10101111100010 >> 2
     00101011111000
3.   100 xor 00101011111000
     --------------
     00000001100100 xor
     00101011111000
     --------------
     00101010011100 = 2716
```